# How to generate hash-key on macOS?

Tags: android, keytool, facebook-authentication

How can I generate a hash key on macOS? According to the instructions on the website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/ I entered into the console: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64. Then I entered the password "android" and wrote to me: The certificate uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.
How to get a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to collision resistance of SHA-1 has been [SHAttered](https://shattered.io/), You can use more secure strategy `sha256`

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: When I insert the key into the field on the site, it says to me: This field must be 28 characters long.

Comment: Oh than for Facebook it's ok to use `sha1`. The warning was from keytool, not from Facebook as they doesn't support `sha256` yet